# RecyclerView Runs well but No result

Tags: android

I followed a tutorial on [youtube](https://youtu.be/Wq2o4EbM74k?list=PLonJJ3BVjZW6CtAMbJz1XD8ELUs1KXaTD) abt `RecyclerView` and wrote the code and adapter which runs with no error but fails to display the list as expected any help pls this area my code

**XML**

custom_list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dummy Text"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:textColor="#ff281c9b" />


</LinearLayout>
```

vanguard_news.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feed_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

**Class Code**

ViewAdapter.class

```
public class ViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <ViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<ReViewInformation> data= Collections.emptyList();

    public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<ReViewInformation> data){
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_row,parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ReViewInformation currObj = data.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(currObj.Title);
        holder.image.setImageResource(currObj.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView title;
        ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_item);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item);

        }
    }
}
```

ReViewInformation.class

```
public class ReViewInformation {
    int id;
    String Title;
}
```

_1Vanguard_News.class

```
public class _1Vanguard_News extends Fragment implements OnRefreshListener{
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ViewAdapter  adapter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vanguard_news, container, false);

        //view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.principal, container, false);
        //Recycle list view
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.feed_list);
        adapter = new ViewAdapter(getActivity(),getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        //Swipe to refresh view
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    public static List<ReViewInformation> getData(){
        List<ReViewInformation> data= new ArrayList();
        int []icons={R.drawable.france,R.drawable.brazil,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
        String []titles={"hgjhgbn","hKHk","hgdjgj"};
        for(int i = 0; i <3; i++){
            ReViewInformation curr = new ReViewInformation();
            curr.id = icons[i];
            curr.Title = titles[i];
            data.add(curr);
        }
        return  data;
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stu
    }

}
```

Screen shot

[image]

Is there something i am missing??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getItemCount()` returns the total number of items in the data set hold by the adapter. If you   `return 0`, the other methods are not called. Change

```
List<ReViewInformation> data= Collections.emptyList();

public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<ReViewInformation> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

to

```
List<ReViewInformation> data;

public ViewAdapter(Context context, List<ReViewInformation> data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}
```

and

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (data == null) {
       return 0;
    }
    return data.size();
}
```